# Proper way to use subdomains for pbf or raster in mapbox gl js

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

The {s}.Link.to.tiles does not work in the "url" for the source. I added all subdomains in "tiles" as an array. Is this the proper way to use subdomains in mapbox gl js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mapbox style spec says of `tiles`:

> An array of one or more tile source URLs, as in the TileJSON spec.

The TileJSON spec says of `tiles`:

> REQUIRED. An array of tile endpoints. {z}, {x} and {y}, if present,
>      are replaced with the corresponding integers. If multiple endpoints are specified, clients
>      may use any combination of endpoints. All endpoints MUST return the same
>      content for the same URL. The array MUST contain at least one endpoint.

So, `{s}` is not supported, and the correct way to specify subdomains is to explicitly list of the full URL in the array, as you're doing.